# How to implement a special selector

Tags: verilog

Is it possible to write a module with 3 wires a,b,c that would output either :

1. z (disconnected) if a=b=c=z
2. a if a=(0 or 1) and b=c=z
3. b if b=(0 or 1) and a=c=z
4. c if c=(0 or 1) and a=b=z
5. x (dont care) otherwise

In verilog?

Comment: Does it need to be synthesizable?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance im a total noob in this field, but do you mean with combinational logic only? if yes then no, it can be clock sensitive

Comment: Does it need to work on FPGA or in an IC design? Or can it be for simulation only? Also is it okay if output non-x when there are not conflicting drivers? For example a=0,b=0,c=z output is 0

Comment: on FPGA, and yes, actually the system garuntees to never drive more then 1 non z value at a time in the inputs, so i dont mind whats gonna go out when there is less then 2 z's

Comment: If it was changed to have active-high selects (==1) rather than just non-Z it becomes quite easy.

Comment: @Morgan yep i know that...

Comment: Digital electronics is designed for 0/1 analysis z can be non-active inputs but no way I know to do this electrically with out special a special analogue comparator which turns 0/1/z in to a 2 bit value. Since this a very hardware topic [ElectronicsSO](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) may be better suited for this question.

Comment: @Morgan thanks ill ask it there

Answer (score 0):

If you have three nets all driving the same wire then this will get what you want in simulation:

```
module three_drive(
  input a,
  input b,
  input c,
  output d);

  assign d=a;
  assign d=b;
  assign d=c;

endmodule
```

However, I don't know what the synthesis would do with that.

It sounds to me like what you really want is to take these three signals and short them together on the input to your FPGA.

Comment: This misses the requirement that x should be the output if more that one input is non-z.

Comment: @Greg one of the comments by the OP says that the system guarantees that only one signal is driven at a time, so he doesn't care about that state.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what the result is if no one is driving it, then nguthrie has the correct answer.  If it needs to be x if it's not driven, then you can do:

```
module three_drive(
  input a,
  input b,
  input c,
  output d);

  wire temp;
  assign temp=a;
  assign temp=b;
  assign temp=c;
  assign d = (temp === 1'bz) ? 1'bx : temp;

endmodule
```

The above is not synthesizable, but it would get the simulation behavior you are looking for.